# python: smtp with TLS delivers no message

Tags: python, ssl, smtplib

I'm trying to send an email through the office365 server.  The email is properly delivered, however the message is not attached

Assistance is most appreciated

```
import smtplib

to = "me@gmail.com"
office365_user = 'announcement@somewhere.com'
office365_pwd = 'password'

smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com",587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.login(office365_user,office365_pwd)
msg = "This is a test email \n"
smtpserver.sendmail(office365_user, to, msg)
smtpserver.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your message is not a valid mail message, which consists of a header and a body. Try something like this:

```
msg = """From: <me@example.com>
To: <you@example.com>
Subject: foo

This is a test email 
"""
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider constructing the message in the same manner as the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/email-examples.html).

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEText("This is a test email")
msg['Subject'] = 'Email Subject'
msg['From'] = 'announcement@somewhere.com'
msg['To'] = 'me@gmail.com'
```

Also, I'm not sure about using `smtpserver.close()`. It seems the proper way is `smtpserver.quit()`.